# Custom class causing errors

Tags: errors, document-classes

I am using a custom [class](https://github.com/emilssolmanis/kursa-darbs/blob/master/ludis.cls) for my thesis.

It is causing errors whenever I try to make a chapter (the class is based on report). I have tracked down that this piece is the one causing the error:

```
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
    \vspace*{50 pt}%
    {\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} \raggedright \normalfont
        \bfseries\Huge
        \ifnum \value{secnumdepth}>1
            \if@mainmatter\thechapter\ %
        \fi
        #1\par\nobreak\vspace{40 pt}}}
```

Could you please take a look and tell what could be causing the problems? I wouldn't mind minor corrections on this piece.

The exact error message is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@makechapterhead ...ecnumdepth}>1 \if@mainmatter
\thechapter \ \fi #1\par \...
l.52 \chapter{Problēmas formulējums}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

This is not the first time I try to use the class and it has always caused these problems on some of the installations.

I am using TexMaker and MikTex 2.9. I use PDFLaTeX for compiling. I tried updating packages and it didn't help. Maybe there is some certain package that I should *work on* harder?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Is it a class or a package? I mean, do you use it as argument to `\documentclass` or to `\usepackage`? If it's a class based on `report`, then it uses `\if@mainmatter` that's inexistent in that class; if it's a package, then use the `book` class as the main one.

Comment: It is included with `\documentclass{ludis}`. You can see the whole class file here if you'd like to - https://github.com/emilssolmanis/kursa-darbs/blob/master/ludis.cls

Comment: Actually, `\documentclass{ludis} \title{My title} \begin{document} \chapter{foo} \end{document}` compiles like a charm, here (I used the very class file you link to). Perhaps you should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs In the file you link, lines 66 and 68 are commented out; line 66 corresponds to your fifth line, while line 68 has disappeared. Copy again the file from the source.

Comment: @egreg woops, I didn't even notice the difference in this resource, I took it from the authors page myself. Has the `report` class changed and `\if@mainmatter` became obsolete at some time or what?

Comment: @egreg, commenting the lines solves the problem and I will accept your answer if you'll write one. I will also notify the author.

Comment: @Juris \f@mainmatter was never in report (it is in book class)